# Передача двух запросов Ajax&Backbone

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

Имеется REST сервер на `Yii2`. Имеется аутентификация типа `Bearer по токену.`
Для тестирования запросов использую **Postman.**
Стучусь к серверу с таким url `jw-server:8888/v1/users` - передаю в запросе `Authorization Bearer ******`. Все ок!

На данный момент разрабатываю приложение на backbone.js и столкнулся с такой проблемой: собираю скрипт аутентификации пользователя в sessionModel. Отправляю запрос от **fetch** по адресу `jw-server:8888/v1/users + '/' + user_id` в ответ получаю 401. Естественно я передаю заголовки Authorization с токеном (причем разными способами - пробовал переопределять backbone.sync, добавлять beforeSend в сам запрос fetch) = бесполезно.
Зашел в safari, открыл консоль и испектор кода. И понял что от меня летят 2 запроса.

1. По данному адресу method `OPTIONS` **без** заголовков Authorization. Возвращает 401 - не зарегистрирован.
2. По данному адресу method `GET` с заголовками и все как надо.

   Как я понимаю сначала идет запрос чтобы узнать, какие типы запросов могут использоваться по адресу, потом летит сам запрос. Но почему то оба бразера Chrome и Safari отвечают мне 401.
   При этом если глянуть в safari на второй документ. Данные приходят. В Chrome же вообще не показывает сколько запросов. Просто - один (401)

Comment: Прочитайте вот это вот: https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain#непростые-запросы. То что происходит - не особенность какой-то библиотеки, а особенность реализации кросдоменного взаимодействия браузерами.

Comment: На этот запрос сервер должен ответить статусом 200, без тела ответа, указав заголовки Access-Control-Allow-Method: метод и, при необходимости, Access-Control-Allow-Headers: разрешённые заголовки.

Comment: В моем же случае сервер отвечает 401. Не авторизован - на запрос OPTIONS